# Erro ao tentar inserir dados de uma tabela mista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou iniciando um projeto MVC e estou com um problema que não consigo corrigir.

```
[Table("InfoGeralEmpresa")]
public class InfoGeralEmpresa
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public InfoGeralEmpresa()
    {
        this.Cliente = new HashSet<Cliente>();
        this.Empresa = new HashSet<Empresa>();
        this.Fornecedor = new HashSet<Fornecedor>();
    }

    public int idInfoGeralEmpresa { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cnpj { get; set; }
    public string razaoSocial { get; set; }
    public string nomeFantasia { get; set; }
    public string inscEstadual { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int idEndereco { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Empresa> Empresa { get; set; }
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Fornecedor> Fornecedor { get; set; }
}
```

E uma classe que herda a `InfoGeralEmpresa`

```
[Table("Empresa")]
public class Empresa : InfoGeralEmpresa
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Empresa()
    {
        this.Cargo = new HashSet<Cargo>();
        this.Cliente = new HashSet<Cliente>();
        this.Fornecedor = new HashSet<Fornecedor>();
        this.Funcionario = new HashSet<Funcionario>();
        this.OrdemServico = new HashSet<OrdemServico>();
        this.Setor = new HashSet<Setor>();
        this.StatusOS = new HashSet<StatusOS>();
    }

    public int idEmpresa { get; set; }
    //public int idInfoGeralEmpresa { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("idInfoGeralEmpresa")]

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Cargo> Cargo { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Fornecedor> Fornecedor { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionario { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrdemServico> OrdemServico { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Setor> Setor { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<StatusOS> StatusOS { get; set; }
    public virtual InfoGeralEmpresa InfoGeralEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Mas quando vou fazer a inserção desta forma:

```
 db.InfoGeralEmpresa.Add(empresa);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Aparece o seguinte erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei mais o que fazer, alguém me ajude.

Comment: Você tem algum motivo para usar `ICollection<Tipo>` ao invés de `List<Tipo>`? Com o código mostrado não vejo nenhum motivo pra isso. Também, creio que você não precise fazer `db.Endereco.Add(empresa.Endereco)` porque ao adicionar `empresa` no contexto, os endereços vão ser criados também, talvez você deva testar e ver se esse é o problema...

Comment: Qual o tipo de `empresa`?